# Loading a .pbf from storage results in CORS error

Tags: android, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS in a Vue.js application to render (.vector).pbf files. Now, using our internal API to get the tiles from a mbtiles file is working fine to render and use the tiles, however the data should also be accessible offline. So I've made a method to get the pbf files from the mbtiles file and zip them together to unpack on the device. (it isn't feasible to package the mbtiles file immediately since it's just under a gigabyte large and not everything is needed, so we're extracting what we need.)

Now this is where my 'issue' comes in. Using the following structure results in a CORS error even though it's loaded from the local storage:

`tilesUrl = "file://" + this.$root.local + "tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.vector.pbf"`

The url makes sense, looking something like this:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.someCompany.someApp/files/active/tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.vector.pbf`

However when I've built it and try to run it through the webview we're using, it's constantly throwing errors regarding CORS. However, we're doing the same to load images, videos and json. Yet only on the pbf files is it throwing a CORS error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS errors will prevail even when the header is on the request because the response is what it will want the header from. Since it can't apply that header through a file:// scheme, it will not accept anything loaded from localstorage. Workaround is to host a simple HTTP server on the device itself with something like [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)